# Convert integer time to String time without Date

Tags: java

I have an integer:

```
int i = 110631;
```

... and I want to convert this to "11:06:31".

I tried using a SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.format(i);
```

... but it's returning 19:01:50.

Comment: convert it to a string, split it in three parts, join the parts with `:` in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another not so efficient approach but uses DateFormat:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format( new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss").parse("" + 110631) )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use division and modulo operators to split the integer into hour, minute and second parts, then concatenate into a String:

```
int i = 110631;

int hours = i / 10000;
int minutes = (i % 10000) / 100;
int seconds = i % 100;

String output = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you get from your code - is just converting Integer to Date. SimpleDateFormat overloaded "format" method contains next code line, which describes your result and actually invoked in your case

```
format(new Date(((Number)obj).longValue()), toAppendTo, fieldPosition);
```

To get what you actually want, consider to use below code:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("hhmmss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(String.valueOf(i));
SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String time = localDateFormat.format(date);
```